# How to post zip file with two string params

Tags: android, post, retrofit

```
byte[] binary = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(reportFile);
    TypedInput binInput = new TypedByteArray("application/zip", binary);
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ContextConstants.REPORT_SUBMIT_PATH)
            .build();
    restAdapter.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);
    http = restAdapter.create(CustomHTTPService.class);
    http.sendReport(stringBuffer.toString(), (userComments != null) ? userComments : "", binInput, new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(String s, Response response) {
            if (response.getStatus() == 200) {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            LOGGER.error("RetrofitError code: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Interface:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/collectFeedback")
void sendReport(@Field("deviceInfo") String deviceInfo, @Field("garbageInfo") String garbageInfo,
                @Body TypedInput binary, Callback<String> response);
```

I`m getting such kinda error:

> retrofit.RetrofitError: CustomHTTPService.sendReport: @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding. (parameter #3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is i solved my issue:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/collectFeedback")
void sendReport(@Part("deviceInfo") TypedString  deviceInfo, @Part("garbageInfo") TypedString  garbageInfo,
                @Part("archive") TypedFile file, Callback<String> response);
```

And interface`s implementation:

```
TypedString deviceInfo = new TypedString(stringBuffer.toString());
    TypedString garbageInfo = new TypedString((userComments != null) ? userComments : "");
    TypedFile archiveFile = new TypedFile("application/zip", reportFile);
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ContextConstants.REPORT_SUBMIT_PATH)
            .build();
    http = restAdapter.create(CustomHTTPService.class);
    http.sendReport(deviceInfo, garbageInfo, archiveFile, new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(String s, Response response) {
            LOGGER.info("response code: " + response.getStatus());
            if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
                boolean deleteResult = reportHelper.deleteCrashDumpFiles();
                LOGGER.info("DeleteFile Result: " + deleteResult);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            LOGGER.error("RetrofitError code: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
```